# Spring MVC for Rest: How set a Locale value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate, spring-mvc-test

I am working with Spring Framework `4.3.2`

About `Rest` for `POST` and `PUT` the following situation happens.

For `POST` I have the following:

```
@PostMapping(consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<Void> saveOne(@Validated @RequestBody Persona persona){
```

Observe the method has declared `@Validated`.

I need do the validation and return the error text message according the `Locale` sent it by the client/user.

I can do it through `Spring MVC Test`, for that I have the following:

```
resultActions = mockMvc.perform(post(uri).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                     .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                     .locale(locale)
                     .content(...content...))).andDo(print());
```

Observe the `.locale(locale)` part.

Until here about `JUnit` through `@Parameters` I am able to send a list of `Locale`s and thus see the error message in different languages. Until here all go how is expected

Now, the other way to access a Rest controller is through `RestTemplate`

I have the following:

```
RequestEntity<Persona> requestEntity = RequestEntity.post(uri)
               .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
               .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)                                                               
               .body(personaValid);

....

ResponseEntity<GenericCollection<ValidatedFieldErrorReport>> responseEntity_ 
  = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, parameterizedTypeReference);
```

Sadly `RequestEntity` through the `post` does not support `.locale(locale)`

Even If I add `.header("Accept-Language", locale.toString())` it does not work, same consideration for `.header("locale", locale.toString())`.

**Note**: I can confirm when I print the `RequestEntity` object it sends the expected `Locale` **but** in the server: it ignores the 'locale' sent it (*how if it never has been not sent it from the beginning*) and uses the default `Locale` available in the server. I am confused with this approach.

I want keep the `RequestEntity` and `ResponseEntity` objects. Their API are fluent.

Therefore what is the correct way?. I am with the impression an extra configuration in either client or server is need it in some place.

Comment: Which locale resolver do you have configured on the server side?

Comment: I only have defined how `@Bean`s a `LocaleChangeInterceptor` and `SessionLocaleResolver` with `new Locale("en","US")` and `registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptorConfig.localeChangeInterceptor())`. Seems missing a `@Bean` according with your question

Comment: So your resolver always returns `new Locale("en","US")`? And you wonder why sending an `Accept-Language` header has no effect?

Comment: The server prints always just `en`. Seems I need define a `@Bean` in the server side.

Comment: It seems I wasn't explicit enough. You get `en` because you have `new Locale("en","US")`. Choose an appropriate locale resolver.

Comment: I am going to check the API, I remember two, one for `Cookie` and `Session` I will check if there are more...

Answer (score 4):

For `RequestEntity` you should use:

```
.header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, locale.toLanguageTag());
```